# receive api data from variable

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to get the api data from the link which is stored in `myData` variable. But the error I get is
`TypeError: myData.find is not a function`

```js
axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/23150699.json')
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data.title)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});

let myData = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/23150699.json';

app.get('/search/:name',(req, res) => {
  myData.find(req.params.name, (err, myData) => {
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    }
      res.json(myData);
  });
});
```

Comment: ```myData``` is an string. You have to make first the api call, if api returns you an array, you can proceed with find operation.

Comment: It's not my API, the api is open source.

Comment: Okay let me put that way, the api end point that you are requesting data sends you a object not a array. You cant make find operation on a object. So what you are trying to archive is not clear. Also inside of app.get referes the myData variable, which is string. Please clearify your question. 

The error message ```TypeError: myData.find is not a function``` is because you are trying to use Array object's method for string so it throws you the error.

Answer (score 0):

there is not enough data to understand your post entirely, but the code will work and extract 'title' from the response

```js
       let myData = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/23150699.json';
       $.get(myData,(req, res) => {
          console.log(req.title);       
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The idea is to get a word used in the req.params.name and not get just a random api call which logs the results of api.